How to tell Mathematica that variables given in the equation are positive integers?
This question is similar to one here, but it's not the same.
Note. I posted the same question on Mathematics StackExchange, but I was advised to ask the question here.
So, I want to ask Mathematica with math input (I don't know natural language) if the following identity holds (of course it does, it's a recurrence for binomials):
$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}$$ for $n, k$ positive integers.
How can I do that?

Try this: FullSimplify[  n!/(k! (-k + n)!) - ((-1 + n)!/(     k! (-1 - k + n)!) + (-1 + n)!/((-1 + k)! (-k + n)!)), {n > 0,    k > 0}] . Have fun!

This works. FunctionExpand[n!/(k!  (-k + n)!) - ((-1 + n)!/(k!  (-1 - k + n)!) + (-1 + n)!/((-1 + k)!  (-k + n)!))] 

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(eqn1 = Binomial[n, k] == 
    Binomial[n - 1, k] + Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]) // TraditionalForm


eqn1 // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(* True *)

(eqn2 = (eqn1 // FunctionExpand) /. 
    Gamma[x_] :> (x - 1)!) // TraditionalForm


eqn2 // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(* True *)

EDIT: Note that no assumptions are necessary. For example:
for reals,
{eqn1, eqn2} /. {n -> 3.7, k -> -8.3}

(* {True, True} *)

for complexes (using arbitrary precision),
{eqn1, eqn2} /. {n -> 3.7`10 - 6.1`10 I, k -> -8.3`10 + 5.8`10 I}

(* {True, True} *)


Your claim "Note that no assumptions are necessary" contradicts to FunctionDomain[  Binomial[n, k] - Binomial[n - 1, k] - Binomial[n - 1, k - 1], {k,    n}, Complexes] which results in Re[n] >= 1 || n \[NotElement] Integers || k \[Element] Integers.

Moreover, this relation is true for positive reals as
FindInstance[FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, k] != Binomial[n - 1, k] + 
Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]], {n,  k}, PositiveReals]


FindInstance::fexp: Warning: FindInstance used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered.{}

shows.
